# How to get auto genetated youtube channel videos (gaming)

Tags: youtube-api

I am new to using the YouTube API. I am trying to get the list of videos generated by YouTube's auto-generated channels.

Let's say https://www.youtube.com/channel/HChfZhJdhTqX8 gives you all the gaming videos within different categories.

Is the are any way to get all the videos under this gaming channel?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GuideCategories](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/guideCategories/list) to get all these guide channels.

A query like

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/guideCategories?part=snippet&regionCode=us&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

will return you all those channel ids related to these categories.

You can always try it under [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/guideCategories/list#try-it).

Comment: Thanks for your reply 

tried the approch you suggested : 

**URL Requested :**
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/guideCategories?part=snippet&id=HChfZhJdhTqX8&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

**Response:**

200 OK
 
- Show headers -
  
{
 "kind": "youtube#guideCategoryListResponse",
 "etag": "\"g-RLCMLrfPIk8n3AxYYPPliWWoo/m9CdmwfER5MtIu3tXvAv_Zbsyw0\"",
 "items": [
 ]
}

Comment: its returning the empty result .Empty Items

Comment: You shouldn't set any id, you should set regioncode as in my example above.

Comment: Looks like there is a bug in api response. URL(https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/guideCategories?part=snippet&regionCode=us&key={YOUR_API_KEY}) is giving the same channel id in resoponse.

Comment: Nope, there is no bug, they all belong to channel "YouTube Spotlight" and you should use the "id" from the items they are all different not the channel id.